# RecyclerView with ViewPager item fail loading

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with different ViewHolders, one of them with a ViewPager. When there's only an item with a ViewPager, it works perfectly fine, but when there's more than one (especially if they are together) only one work fine and the others or disappear or show the same content of the working one. It only happens with the ViewPager because any other kind of view in the list item works perfectly.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private Context mContext;

public ViewHolder(View itemView){
    super(itemView);
    mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new PagerFragment(),"");
    adapter.addFragment(new PagerFragment(),"");
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: maybe use two different adapters ??

Comment: Can you send the code?